# When using the matrix command on a dataframe, it produces a list

Tags: r

Hopefully I haven't missed this being asked elsewhere when I looked, it seems basic enough that it should already be addressed but I couldn't find it.

I have a data frame (data_ordered) that looks like this:

```
  LAME_chem Year       prop
1    BR_Res 2006 0.07731959
4    BR_Res 2007 0.15568862
7    BR_Res 2008 0.04494382
2    FW_Res 2006 0.12886598
5    FW_Res 2007 0.01796407
8    FW_Res 2008 0.34831461
3   Migrant 2006 0.79381443
6   Migrant 2007 0.82634731
9   Migrant 2008 0.60674157
```

Where both LAME_chem and Year are factors.

I am attempting to convert it to a matrix with the following code:

```
data = matrix(data_ordered, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

it produces a list of 3 elements, the first being the 3 levels of LAME_chem, the second being the levels of Year, and the third being all the values of prop. What's going on? This should be relatively straightforward shouldn't it?

-edit- I figured it out. The code I wrote apparently asked it to make three matrices, one of each column, when what I wanted was a matrix of the prop values with the rows and columns being the LAME_chem and Years, using data_ordered$prop worked

```
data = matrix(data_ordered$prop, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: try `as.matrix(data_ordered)`

Comment: @AdamSpannbauer thanks, that would have worked for what I described in the question, but I realized that that wasn't actually what I needed to do, I've edited it now that I figured it out.

Comment: Consider posting the fix you found as an answer, so others can find it.

Answer (score 0):

For the issue as I originally described it, @AdamSpannbauer had the best solution:

```
data = as.matrix(data_ordered)
```

For what I was actually trying to do, I had to specifically call just the column I was trying to turn into a matrix

```
data = matrix(data_ordered$prop, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```